# using ajax on iphone,android platform

Tags: mobile

sir,I was developing mobile  site for  iPhone,android  platform .Can i use ajax  with php and how can be implement  java script. ,is it support the  java script in this platform. please help me

Comment: Sir or madam, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iPhone/Android support JavaScript. Do what you'd do for desktop browsers and the JavaScript will work just fine.